# How to bind CKEditor to a Textbox in ASP.NET 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

How do I bind [CKEditor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CKEditor) to a Textbox in ASP.NET 3.5? I have a Control ID, but this changes when a page is opened in the browser.

ASP.NET 3.5 does not have ClientID Feature.

Comment: No, i am using the pure javascript version. And there is no usercontrol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a possible way:

The use of a class instead of the control id. Found here:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:editor_selector